# Significance of Resource name in tomcat context

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, server.xml

Can someone please explain me what is the significance of Resource name in context.xml.
My question is similar to "[How does the Resource name attribute in Tomcat's context.xml work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625015/how-does-the-resource-name-attribute-in-tomcats-context-xml-work)"

Explaination:
In my server.xml i have two contexts for two different applications.

```
1.<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/app1"></Resource></Context>

2.<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/app2"></Resource></Context>
```

When i use app1 for both context resource name, both applications works fine. But if i give app2 application gives me error as "Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'"

What is the problem?

Comment: Please specify your question - it is too generic. What do you want to do? What is your problem? Or is it an academic question about theoretical possibilities with using Resource name in context.xml?

Comment: NiklasP My question is same as provided in the link above.

Comment: Are those your complete Context tags? There is a lot missing ie. `type`, `driverClassName`, `url` etc.

Comment: @CodeWarrior Its not complete context, i just added sample.

Answer (score 0):

The resource's `name` would more appropriately be called its *path*. This is the path, rooted at `java:comp/env`, within the JNDI namespace. This value will be used by your code to locate the object within the JNDI namespace at the same location.

Ref: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/globalresources.html#Resource_Definitions